# MediaPlayer.Open plays a sound that it opens

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-media-player

I have this:

```
MediaPlayer[] sounds = new MediaPlayer[40];

private void LoadSamples()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sounds.Length; i++)
    {
        try { sounds[i].Open(new Uri([my path here])); } catch { }
    }
}
```

This code works as it should, BUT during the loop (when the sounds are opened) these sounds are played in the program and I don't need this to happen. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think this help you sounds[i].Pause(); you can pause for dont play media file

Comment: I tried this, I also tried sounds[i].Stop(), but that doesn't work...

Comment: i dont khow how you config media player but in my system after call open I must call Play to play music and dont occurred

Comment: I load the sounds here and then check for keyboard press to play a specific sound